# Commutator subgroup being characteristic in commutator group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H$ be a characteristic subgroup of group $G$?

Then is it true that $H'$ is a characteristic subgroup of $G'$? If it is, then how can I show this?

$G'$ here means the group generated by all the commutators in $G$.

So $G'$ = $<[a,b]: a,b \in  G$>$

Here $[a,b]$ = $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$

So to prove this it is sufficient to show that $f(H') \subset H'$ for every automorphism f in $G'$

I am not able to make use of the fact that $H$ is characteristic subgroup of $G$ from here and prove.

Should I use that $H'$ is characteristic in $H$ and $H$ is characteristic in $G$?

Therefore by transitive property, $H'$ is characteristic in G.

How can I move forward from here?

Or is there any counter example to disprove the above statement

Comment: Why do you think that the statement you are trying to prove is true?

Comment: OH..Is it not?..Actually I was trying to prove an exercise(which wasn't this)..But I thought that if I am able to show this, then I will be able to prove that.

Comment: If you are uncertain, then you should ask whether it is true, not ask for help proving it, which might waste people's time. I think there are counterexamples of order $32$.

Comment: I am sorry. I'll just edit the question.

Comment: @DerekHolt - perhaps you could reveal the counterexample in a formal answer, so that in the future one can refer to this.

Comment: The issue is that there may be automorphisms of $G'$ which are not induced by automorphisms of $G$. So although $H'$ will be fixed by all the $G$-automorphisms of $G'$, it may not be fixed by the new ones.

Answer (score 3):

I suspected that this property did not hold (mainly because there did not seem to be any reason why it should, which I know is not a reliable guide). Anyway, I found a counterexample of order $32$ by computer search, so I will just exhibit the GAP calculation:

```
gap> G := SmallGroup(32,6);;
gap> L := LowIndexSubgroups(G,2);;
gap> IsCharacteristicSubgroup(G,L[3]);
true
gap> DG := DerivedSubgroup(G);;
gap> DL3 := DerivedSubgroup(L[3]);;
gap> IsCharacteristicSubgroup(DG,DL3);
false
```

Comment: Thanks Derek, appreciated! +1 from me.